# displaying svg using the embed tag in ie9

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9

Hey everyone, I was just wondering whether anybody had any experience with displaying svg in ie9 using the embed tag. Below is an example of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Example</title></head>
<body>
<embed id="E" height="50%" width="100%" src="example.svg">
</body>
</html>
```

Right now this displays just fine in Firefox, ie 8 with the Adobe plugin, however in ie 9 it just pops up a blank box with an image icon in the top left of the box. Does anybody have any ideas how I could fix this problem?

Comment: Out of interest what Document Mode is IE9 using when viweing your HTML? I think the post may describe the problem and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111785/inline-svg-content-not-displaying-in-ie-screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Althought your snippet includes a HTML5 DocType definition there are other factors which affect exactly how IE9 processes your HTML e.g. *HTTP Response Headers* (see [How Internet Explorer Chooses Between Document Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803%28v=VS.85%29.aspx))

I think if you force IE9 into Standards mode your SVG will be rendered by IE9; to quickly test this just use the [Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705#_Dev_Tools) to control Browser and Document modes.

So, if your embdeded SVG now shows you're just left with figuring out what's triggering IE9 to select the wrong Document Mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your question means that you're trying to figure out any way to display SVG in IE9, or specifically only with the `<embed>` tag. If you just want a way to display SVG in IE9, I recommend embedding SVG directly in XHTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>untitled</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body { background:#eee; margin:1em }
    svg  { background:#fff; display:block; border:1px solid #ccc; width:100%; margin:1em -1px }
  </style>
</head><body>
<svg viewBox="-500 -500 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full">
  <!-- SVG content here -->
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
  var svg   = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
  var svgNS = svg.getAttribute('xmlns');
  // Access/manipulate your SVG here
]]></script>
</body></html>
```

If you want to test this technique, here are some examples (on my site) using SVG that work in IE9:

- http://phrogz.net/svg/rainbowgrid.xhtml
- http://phrogz.net/svg/3-point-circle2.xhtml
- http://phrogz.net/svg/stirling_numbers.xhtml
- http://phrogz.net/svg/soldiers.xhtml
- http://phrogz.net/svg/drag_under_transformation.xhtml
- http://phrogz.net/svg/complex_butterfly.xhtml

If this is not what you want, please clarify what your needs are.