# Inline SVG Content not displaying in IE Screenshot

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9

I'm working on a thumbnailer whereby a service takes thumbnail images of HTML content in a form-less IE9 control. Everything is working smoothly with a DrawToBitmap call along with a couple of GDI calls, but SVG content is not displaying. Everything else seems to display just fine, but no SVG.

I figure that this has something to do with how SVG is implemented in IE, but I don't know the details. Any thoughts?

TIA.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer came from Ted Johnson of IEBlog:

> IE9 has no separate SVG engine; it’s all one DOM and rendering
> pipeline. However, if your document isn’t in 9 standards document
> mode, you’ll not get any SVG content. I think, by default, the
> WebBrowser control in .NET defaults to compatibility mode. Try adding
> a meta tag to the top of your HTML page to force IE9 mode:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
> ```

This, indeed, turned on SVG rendering like a light switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a doctype of HTML4 strict or HTML5.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

From http://www.seowarp.com/blog/2011/06/svg-scaling-problems-in-ie9-and-other-browsers/ :

> Before I begin, I’d just like to point out that on my test page, Internet Explorer 9 refused to display any of my SVG images on a basic HTML page until I declared the HTML4 strict or HTML5 doctypes.