# HTML not displaying correctly on network drive

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using HTML to create some automatically generated test reports for work. The reports display fine when they are stored locally on my C:\ drive, but when I copy the report to a work network drive for general access the html doc no longer displays correctly in IE9:

- Where there should be a figure with an SVG file displayed, the page just ends (i.e. none of the subsequent content is displayed).
- Formatting of things such as figure captions gets messed up.

The reports consist of figures which are relative path linked SVG files stored in the same folder as the HTML doc.

I'd really appreciate any pointers anyone could give on why there is this difference when viewing from a network drive as opposed to my local C:\ drive.

Many thanks

Ben

Comment: Please review [ask] questions on SO

Comment: Do you have any code? or is this question for mind readers only?

Comment: Can you supply some of your code so we can see how you are garbing your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IE document mode can be different depending where the file is stored. For example, it can set Mode IE7 for all intranet pages. The same can occurs if you're on another drive.

Because SVG is supported since IE9, a IE8- document mode can remove this support.

Check in the IE dev tools (`F12`) if there is a document mode difference between each drive or add this meta to force IE to the edge mode :

```
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Many thanks Miam84 & javascriptCoder, the document was being displayed in IE7 mode when loaded from the network drive, and your solutions solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in head section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

For more details please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111785/inline-svg-content-not-displaying-in-ie-screenshot)

OR

You can add 100% width to parent element, which does some magic.